# ajax submission without page refresh not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

i have an anchor tag named "save as draft".

**Expected functionality**

When i click on this link the values in my form fields should get stored into the DB. But the fields should not be refreshed and should retain the values.

**Anchor link**

```
<a class="btndisable" href="#" id="saveasdraft" onclick="draft();">SAVE
                                                AS DRAFT</a>
```

**My Script**

```
function draft() {

    document.getElementById("status").value = "DRAFT";
    $("#addaccount").serialize();
    $.ajax({

        type : "POST",
        url : './requestDetails',
        data : $("#addaccount").serialize(),
        success : function() {
            console.log("inside draft ajax method....");
            $('#dbmsg').show();
            console.log("inside draft ajax method 2....");
            $("#addscenario").addClass('btn');
        }
    });
```

The problem here is when i submit the form through ajax the fields get refreshed

Need your suggestion

Comment: because the form is being submitted automatically?

Comment: `event.preventDefault()`? inside your `draft()` method

Comment: can you post your html markup for whole form element and also what is your server side scripting?

Comment: Hey Sandeep.. That works..!! Thank  you..

Answer (score 0):

add   `href="javascript:void(0);"` to your anchor tag.This may help you to refreshing your page

Comment: i dont want to refresh the page.. i want to retain it after form submission via ajax..

Comment: This is not allow the page to refreshing.This take page to steady without refreshing page

Answer (score -1):

Add `return false;` to your code

```
function draft(e) {
e.preventDefault();
document.getElementById("status").value = "DRAFT";
$("#addaccount").serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: './requestDetails',
    data: $("#addaccount").serialize(),
    success: function () {
        console.log("inside draft ajax method....");
        $('#dbmsg').show();
        console.log("inside draft ajax method 2....");
        $("#addscenario").addClass('btn');
    }
});

return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think this would work? You added the `return false` in the `success` function, not in the `draft` function. The `a` elements `onclick` attribute needs to recieve the `false`, so I think that `draft` needs to return `false`? Or do `onclick="draft();return false;"`

Comment: No. It still refresh the contents